# useCallback Type Hook That Updates Immediately on Dependency Update

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

I was very mistaken about the behavior of `useCallback` hook.
I was under the impression that let's say if I had a code like this

```
const [value1, setValue1] = useState(null);
const [value2, setValue2] = useState(null);
const [value3, setValue3] = useState(null);

const foo = useCallback(() => console.log(value1, value2, value3), [value1, value2, value3])
```

and if I call a function that looks like this

```
function bar() {
   setValue1(1);
   setValue2(2);
   setValue3(3);

   foo();
}
```

I should always get a copy of the function `foo` that has all the updated dependencies. Which means the output should be

```
1 2 3
```

But it isn't. It's

```
null null null
```

So I'm using the useCallback hook wrong. Is there a hook that does what I want from a useCallback hook?

Comment: can you share the entire code where "bar" is implemented?

Comment: @vipul, calling `setValue1` does not (and can not) change the value in the local const `value1`, so `foo` also can't see that new value. `setValue1` just asks react to rerender the component. On that new render you'll create new local variables, but code from your old render has no access to those. I suggest you rework the `foo` function so you can pass values into it, as in `foo(1, 2, 3)`. Then you can manually pass in the values which you just updated the state to be.